# jquery mobile basic formatting with align center

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, alignment, center

I just can't get the button to align center here. What am I doing wrong? Also, I need to add an image next to the title text and they both together should be aligned center. How do I do it?

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageMain">

<div data-role="content" align="bottom">    
    <div id ="mainDiv2">
        <table border="1" align="CENTER" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div id="question">
            Test
            <Style>
                #question{
                  font:16px;
                }
            </style>        
            </div>
        </td></tr><tr>
        <td align="center">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><button id="button1" type="submit" data-theme="c">test</button></div>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO strange and unnecessary combination of table + JQM grid...

Is that close enough to what you wanted?

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageMain">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" align="bottom">    
        <div style="
            background-image: url(http://twitter.com/images/resources/twitter-bird-light-bgs.png);
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;" data-role="none"></div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Your text goes here</h1>
        <button id="button1" type="submit" data-theme="c">test</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle for this is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fWAEe/)

Comment: peterm - Yes, thanks! Just needed an image to be a thumbnail right next to the text on top. Might be able to figure it out but if you can out together something quick, please do!